# How to perform local search on the map in windows phone 8 app

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8, bing-maps

I want to perform **string based** search on the map in a windows phone 8 app.

On searching on net I got this on msdn website -

```
            BingMapsTask bingMapsTask = new BingMapsTask();

            bingMapsTask.SearchTerm = "coffee";
            bingMapsTask.ZoomLevel = 2;

            bingMapsTask.Show();
```

But this opens a new window(or app) showing the search results. I have two questions -

1. How can I get input from the new window, I mean I want that when user would touch any of the search results my app should get its co-ordinate. How to do it ?
2. Is there any way to perform the search in the app itself ?

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`GeocodeQuery`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/microsoft.phone.maps.services.geocodequery%28v=vs.105%29.aspx) to look up the coordinates of a search term.

```cs
// Get your current position
var myPosition = await new Geolocator().GetGeopositionAsync(TimeSpan.FromMinutes(1), TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10));

// Define search
var geoQuery = new GeocodeQuery();
geoQuery.SearchTerm = "Seattle, WA";
geoQuery.GeoCoordinate = new GeoCoordinate(myPosition.Coordinate.Latitude, myPosition.Coordinate.Longitude);
geoQuery.QueryCompleted += (s, e) => {
  if (e.Error == null && e.Result.Count > 0) {
    // e.Result will contain a list of coordinates of matched places.
    // You can show them on a map control , e.g.
    myMap.Center = e.Result[0].GeoCoordinate;
    myMap.ZoomLevel = 2;
  }
}
geoQuery.QueryAsync();
```

Note, you need `ID_CAP_MAP` added for this to work.